# what is type to use with oracle spatial column in ef core code first?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, spatial

I have asp.net core project work fine with mssql my manager decide to use oracle, and we have sqlGeometry columns that we store spatial information, we are new to oracle and we still discover things,SDO_GEOMETRY in oracle is equivelant to sqlgeometry ,but we don't know how can we map it to our code first project?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for same problem. Could you find a solution? I'd be happy if you share.